# Connecting to Teradata using SQLAlchemy results in errors

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, teradata

I'm trying to connect to Teradata with SQLAlchemy and then save the results as pandas.DataFrame.

```
engine = create_engine(f"teradata://{UID}:{PWD}@host/?dsn={DSN}")
query = """SELECT TOP 10 * from db_5.mobile_sa"""
with engine.connect() as connect:
    df = pd.read_sql(query,connect)
```

This results in an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (teradata.api.DatabaseError) (11470, '[HYC00] [Cloudera][ODBC] (11470) Transactions are not supported.') (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)
```

I've found that I should try to set autocommit to true, so I tried solutions from [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#setting-isolation-level-or-dbapi-autocommit-for-an-engine) and added `isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT"` to `create_engine()` , but this time I got

```
TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'isolation_level' sent to create_engine(), using configuration TeradataDialect/SingletonThreadPool/Engine.  Please check that the keyword arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.
```

I also tried to add `&autocommit=true` to connection url, but that didn't seem to have an effect.
How do I go around it?

Comment: As per [this Github comment](https://github.com/Teradata/sqlalchemy-teradata/issues/86#issuecomment-541789406) it sounds like you should switch to the newer [teradatasqlalchemy](https://pypi.org/project/teradatasqlalchemy) dialect.

Comment: Switching `teradata` for `teradatasql` throws an error that "dsn" is an unknown field. Is it possible to connect to a user defined DSN?

Comment: Probably not, because AFAIK the new dialect does not use ODBC. You would just plug the values for `Server=`, `Database=`, etc. from the DSN into your connection URL.

Comment: That's good to know. While I managed to connect to Teradata database, I'm intimidated by another, with "Cloudera for Apache Hive" driver since there are more settings in DSN setup like a couple of hosts, Hive Server Type or Zookeeper Namespace. I'll search for the way to set it up, but I'd appreciate any additional tips

Comment: Just pointing out that the error above indicates the DSN you were passing is using Cloudera ODBC driver, not a Teradata.  And yes, teradatasql dialect / teradatasqlalchemy is preferred (and does not use ODBC).

Comment: @Fred Right, I kind of mixed in the two connections I've been trying to work out. I couldn't make a working copy with hive dialect either. Anyways, I've searched for a while but can't find a way for multiple hosts to work, as it was supposed to work in ODBC configuration. I've only seen a post about postgres and multiple hosts there, but it didn't seem to be resolved.

Comment: If by "multiple hosts" you mean "multiple server nodes in the same system / cluster" the Teradata drivers can do that. See the description of "COP discovery".  If you mean two entirely separate systems with a single connection object, then none of the standard drivers will do that.

Comment: I've connected to teradata just fine now, so I think that I should start another question about problems with connection to hive.